# What is lightweight text editor that i can port on a microcontroller?

Tags: text-editor, microcontroller, firmware

I want to port a text editor on Microcontroller. I may use TI's stellaris or STM32 microcontroller for the implementation of same. I had came accross leafpad text editor which is light version which can fit in limited memory requirements. I need suggestions.

Comment: need to provide more information, how big do you think these text files/data will be?  What kind of storage are you planning to use with the device if any (to store this text data).  Are you planning on having an operating system of some kind to run this application on.  What is the user interface, the display of the text and the user input?  How much work have you done so far examining the source for the candidates that you are trying to port?

Comment: The interface will be Graphic LCD and Keypad as well as VGA. Storage will be SD card. Files will be not of more size will Max of 100Kb. I will be doing all in Firmware no OS will be used. Other interface things i am already known about how to it (Most of part i am ready with). I didnt study a source code for porting yet, i am deciding to  study and port it based on size and my device is not a computer, it will be a simple embedded device with low memory capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a graphics library and fashion a "simple as you like" line editor.

**Outline**

Mr Microchip has a free Graphics Display Designer program which will generate code for all the display driving primitives in various modes. (ie VGA mono and would use a graphics controller)

Then I suggest (starting with) three display elements ( four lines of pre-context, one line of segment to edit and four lines of post context) which can be made out of static text boxes and an edit box (if line is longer than the display width,  then line is broken into multiple segments )

So on initial read of your file the pre-context would be empty and the first segment would be the first line upto the display width. The post context would be made from the balance of the first line or subsequent lines

From then on, coordinate either editing the line segment (and writing back any changes) or navigating the file. Add features as required.

Also as you say "File>s<" the same graphic design could be used with the SD card file system (also available) to enable selecting a file for editing from a list of files.

**Additional**

This guy has effected an editor feature on an AVR that uses a two line LCD and internal non-volatile memory. There is a link on for the source code.

Text Editor on AVR ATmega16 with PS/2 keyboard and LCD

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2SDs7H5KDE